# How can I see the bugs open for different versions?

Tags: bug-reporting

Where can I see the criticals bugs for ubuntu versions?

For example (this information is merely an example from my head not the reality):
 - 14.04  300 bugs (100 critical)
 - 14.10 (after official released ) 600 bugs (200 critical)?

The reason I ask is because I want to be sure before upgrading to an non LTS that major bugs are fixed. For the LTS upgrades, there is the 3 month before the first point release. For the non LTS there is no point releases.

Comment: While https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu has links for *"Series-targeted bugs"*, I think you might be asking about something else. What are you looking for exactly? If you're seeing the text you've included in your question, *where* are you seeing it? Please [edit] this question to provide this and any other information you think might be relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the open bug list for Ubuntu 14.04

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+bugs

553 Open bugs, 14 Critical bugs

---

Open bug list for Ubuntu 14.10

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+bugs

187 Open bugs, 4 Critical bugs